# UNUserNotification doesn't work after updating to swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, unusernotificationcenter

So I had an interacitve push notification but it suddenly stopped working,
this is my code:

```
func pushNotification(){
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    let answer1 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "answer1", title: "thank you!", options: UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground)

    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myCategory", actions: [answer1, answer2], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    //Created notification
    content.body = "how are you?"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"
    content.badge = 1
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}



@objc(userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:) func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    {

        if response.actionIdentifier == "answer1"
        {
            print("ok")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "FastResult", sender: self)
        }

        completionHandler()
    }
```

when I run the app I get the notification but I doen't recive the output: "ok" and there is no segue.

Answer (score 0):

response.actionIdentifier == "answer1" only will be true when you tap on "thank you!" option in the notification. It wont be true if you just tap the notification. please check

Comment: Checked it, from some reason it doesn't work even tho I press it

Comment: I only give :
let answer1 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "answer1", title: "thank you!", options: UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground)
        
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myCategory", actions: [answer1], intentIdentifiers: [], options: []).